# Parameter retrieval from RestRequest

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have 3 environments (Dev, Uat/Qa and Prod/Live) and all have Visual Studio 2019.
Currently I am working on a project on Dev and transferred the code to Uat, but I am getting different methods/properties on the RestRequest object, using exactly the same version of RestSharp (108.0.3).
I use .Net framework 4.7.2 and RestSharp netstandard2.0.

On dev I can use the following to get the value.

```
RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); //This line is temporary to show the issue 
var lastParam = req.Parameters.Last().**Value**;
```

On Uat I can use the following to get the value (different method).

```
RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); //This line is temporary to show the issue 
var lastParam = req.Parameters.Last().**get_Value**();
```

[Dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1KVr.png)
[Uat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yhd5.png)

The only difference I can spot from the Metadata of the RestSharp class between the 2 environments is some additional annotations on the methods.

On Dev:

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Default constructor
        public RestRequest();
        public RestRequest(string? resource, Method method = Method.Get);
        public RestRequest(Uri resource, Method method = Method.Get);
```

On Uat:

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Default constructor
        public RestRequest();
        [NullableContextAttribute(2)]
        public RestRequest(string resource, Method method = Method.Get);
        public RestRequest(Uri resource, Method method = Method.Get);
```

I have removed and installed numeral times the RestSharp library from Visual Studio (2019), but there was no success.

I cannot pinpoint where the problem could be.

I hope someone could help.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter what Visual Studio version you have installed. Check what .NET Framework or .NET SDKs are installed on those machines.

The issue you describe is caused by an old SDK that doesn't support record types, and `RestParameter` is a record.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I will explore that and make all the environments the same where there's a mismatch. Thank you for your help.